# Relinux Live CD - waiting for network configuration

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, remastersys

I installed ubuntu 12.04 base system via minimal ubuntu iso. I make a script to get hostname from dhcp server which explained [here](http://nxhelp.com/blog/2013/1/24/automatically-set-hostname-from-dhcp-in-debian-using-isc-dhcp-client). It works perfect. I don't install network manager because I dont need it. Then I made an livecd.iso with relinux. It always shows "waiting for network configuration" and my script doesn't work when boot with livecd.iso(it shows same result with remastersys). I realize that it doesn't give this waiting message if i install network manager. But at this time, my script stops again because network manager doesn't hooks dhclient-exit-hooks.d. Relinux also changes my /etc/network/interfaces. It adds "eth1", "wlan" etc. After some research i use [this solution](https://petermolnar.eu/linux-tech-coding/ubuntu-11-10-disable-waiting-up-to-60-more-seconds-for-network-configuration/) to fix it but ubuntu starts without network configuration. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You need to make sure your non-NM setup works correctly. I'm afraid that will mean falling back to all sorts of halfway forgotten commands and do things by hand. Check carefully how much resources NM really takes, it is inmensely flexible and works fine even in weird cases that you don't want to have to handle by hand.

Comment: Non-NM setup works correctly on ubuntu. It doens't work on live cd. It always shows "waiting for network configuration" message and fails when boot with live cd. So I lose chance to get hostname from dhcp server.